# origen-imagen función c++

Tags: c++, funciones, loops, matrices

hay un ejercicio resuelto que encontré que compila  bien pero que no entiendo el código que se ha utilizado.

contextualizo un poco:

> Considérese   un  conjunto finito de  número  enteros consecutivos
>   A =   {1, 2,  …,  n}. Defínase    una relación en el  producto    cartesiano R Í
>   AxA,  donde   cada    par (i,j) representa    que el  elemento    i está
>   relacionado   con el  elemento    j mediante  R. Se   representará la 
>   relación   R mediante  un  objeto  de  tipo    matrix_t,  donde   el 
>   elemento   (i,j) de    dicha   matriz tomará el    valor   1 si    i está relacionado con j mediante  R,  o   cero    en  caso    contrario.  Cuando  sea necesario   denominaremos   al  elemento    i
>   del   par (i,j) origen,   y    a  j imagen.
>   Se    dese    comprobar   si  la  relación    R   cumple  ciertas propiedades para    lo  cual    se  requiere    los siguientes  métodos:
>
> Impleméntese  el  método  bool    matrix_t::is_func(void),   el  cual    devuelve    verdadero   si  la  relación    descrita    en  la  matriz   es  una     función,    o   falso   en  caso    contrario.  Es  decir, 
>   devuelve   verdadero   si todo     origen  tiene   una     imagen,     y   a  todo
>   origen     le  corresponde    únicamente  una imagen.

este es el código que probé y compila y funciona a las mil  marvillas, pero no lo entiendo.

más abajo detallo mis dudas

```
bool is_func(void)
{ bool is_fun = true;
  int  i      = 1;

  while ((is_fun == true) && (i <= get_m())) {
    int sum_row = 0;
    for (int j = get_n(); j >= 1; j--)
      sum_row += get(i,j);

    if (sum_row != 1)
      is_fun = false;
    i++;
  }
  return is_fun;
}
```

Mi duda:

¿por qué la variable `j` es decreciente en el segundo `for`?
¿por qué se comprueba que la suma de los elementos de cada elemento es? yo entiendo que para que sea la matriz una función todas las posiciones de la misma tienen que tener como valor un 1, no solo una fila, entonces eso que os pregunto no lo acabo de ver

¿Por qué i se incrementa dentro del `if`?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**¿por qué la variable j es decreciente en el segundo for?** 
Por que va recorriendo las filas de la matriz para obtener los valores y sumarlos en sum_row = (i,j) + (i, j-1) + (i, j-2) + ... + (i, 1)

**¿por qué se comprueba que la suma de los elementos de cada elemento es?** 
Es, según el enunciado, la forma de determinar si la relación en la matriz es una función (true si la suma es 1) o no (false si la suma no es 1)

**¿Por qué i se incrementa dentro del if?** 
*i* no se incrementa dentro del *if* si no fuera de él

Comment: ok, gracias por aclararme bastante  las cosas , pero sigo teniendo dudas para entender la primera pregunta, ¿también  se podría recorrer las columnas empezando desde la primera, en j=1?

Comment: muchas    gracias por la respuesta

Comment: _j_ recorre las filas e _i_ las columnas. El enunciado del ejercicio dice _devuelve verdadero si todo origen tiene una imagen, y a todo origen le corresponde únicamente una imagen_ es decir hay que comprobar que _origen_ o sea _i_ tiene **una** (1) imagen (_j_). Recorrer las columnas desde la primera fila como dices, no respondería al ejercicio a no ser que traspusieras la matriz

Comment: Hola @Josemi, eso más o menos lo tengo claro, mi duda es por qué se recorren las columnas  de manera decreciente,  for (int j = get_n(); j >= 1; j--)

Comment: Hola @AER. Recorren las filas no las columnas. ¿Por qué de forma decreciente?. Es irrelevante como lo haga ya que lo que se busca en esta operación es la suma de todos los valores situados en columna y filas sucesivas. Si lo hiciera de forma creciente, funcionaria igual. Yo me decanto mas por la decreciente por evitar el uso de **get_n()** en la condición y así evitar evaluarlo cada vez, es más rápido, es sólo por eficiencia

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus respuestas

Comment: me quedó todo claro.